# Pandas - How to sort values for multiple columns but ensure every value in columns appear in order?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, parallel-coordinates

I have df with multiple columns (categories) with 5-8 numbers (groups) per category. I am trying to make a parallel category plot with plotly (https://plotly.com/python/parallel-categories-diagram/) with a set order for each category. The groups' order in the plot is the order of appearace in the df. All works well after sorting the dataframe except when some combination is missing, which messes the order of the missing group.

Example df:

```
df.sort_values(by=['A','B','C','D'],ascending=True,inplace=True)
A     B     C     D
0     0     0     0
0     0     0     2
0     0     1     0
0     0     1     1
```

So for category D, the group 2 will be plotted before group 1. I need a way to ensure all groups apear in order but the rows have to be mantained since it is groups assigned to users. Is there a way to achieve the following result instead?

```
A     B     C     D
0     0     0     0
0     0     1     1
0     0     0     2
0     0     1     0
```

Bonus points if a fake row is added when the ordering becomes impossible. For example if we had

```
df.sort_values(by=['A','B','C','D'],ascending=True,inplace=True)
A     B     C     D
0     0     0     0
0     0     0     2
0     0     1     0
0     0     2     1
```

there would be no way to have Column D in order without breaking the columns, so in this case I would like to add a fake row

```
df.sort_values(by=['A','B','C','D'],ascending=True,inplace=True)
A     B     C     D
0     0     0     0
0     0     0     1
0     0     0     2
0     0     1     0
0     0     1     1
```

Or if anyone knows another way to set up the order in the parallel categories graph so it never moves that would also work.

Thank you.

Edited for clarity

Comment: What do you expect? In the linked example you also see lines that are crossing.

Comment: Yes, lines will always cross, but if the group order changes that makes it challenging to assign tags since I would have to check the order every time and it also makes it very difficult for stakeholders to compare results at two different points in time because the groups in each category in the graph won't have the same order. I edited the question for clarity, let me know if it still does not make sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is `not` sort, but to change entire data

Simply run `sort` for each Series and use `concat` to stack them

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[3,1,4,2],
                   'c2':['x','y','x','y'],
                   'val':[8,4,5,9]})

temdf = pd.DataFrame()

for col in ['c1', 'c2', 'val']:
    temcol = df[f'{col}'].copy()
    temcol.sort_values(inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
    temdf = pd.concat([temdf, temcol], axis=1)
```

Comment: My apologies if my explanation was not clear, but I need to maintain the rows as they are groups assigned to each user.

Comment: @LaiaFerrer-Argemí: I am sorry but I do not understand what you want. Perhaps a more detail sample and an expected outcome would help.

Comment: I edited the question for clarity, let me know if it still does not make sense!

Comment: @LaiaFerrer-Argemí: I am sorry but your expected output does not follow any rule that can be producible. Unless you give a longer example, otherwise it does not make any sense for col `D` the order is 0,1,2 then 0 again